# List all post title in category using functions.php

Tags: functions

I have search all google about this. But many of theme show the way to make a new Template Page which you can choose template type for page.

But i want it directly show post title in category by using the functions.php in my theme.

The code is

```
<?php if ( is_category() ) : ?>
<li>
<h2>News</h2><ul>
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=date&order=ASC');
 foreach($posts as $post) :
 ?>

<li>
<a>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</li>
<?php endif ; ?>
```

Any suugestions on how to convert it to function for in use in functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact approach here is, but the above can be converted easily into a function. I have commented the code so you can follow it. (*Requires PHP 5.4 as it uses the short array syntax. Also, I have not included markup, you need to add it as needed*)

```
function category_post_list()
{
    /*
     * Stop function and return null this function is used outside of a
     * a category archive page
     */
    if ( !is_category() )
        return null;

    /*
     * Get the current category ID with get_queried_object_id()
     */ 
    $category_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $args = [
        'cat' => $category_id,
        'nopaging' => true, // The same as posts_per_page => -1
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
    }
    /*
     * Very important reset all postdata if a custom query changed it
     */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

You can then use it as follow

```
category_post_list();
```

On the other hand, if you just going to use your category pages as a page to list post titles, you can simply use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query accordingly to set the posts per page to -1, which will be more efficient. Add this into functions.php, this code will return all the posts in a category. (*Requires PHP 5.3*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) 
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_category() ) {
        $q->set( 'nopaging', true );
    }
});
```

You can then just use the default loop in category.php

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );

}
```

This will give you the same exact effect as the custom function

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: @Pieter Goosen, please end while loop